# Deserializing XML from a NetworkStream fails

Tags: c#, .net, xml-deserialization, networkstream

I have my application set up to send objects over the network by serializing them into XML on the sending side and deserializing them on the receiving side. I first set it up with UDP, which worked fine. Code like so:

Sender:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
dataSerializer.Serialize(ms, dataToSend, serNamespaceRemover);
senderClient.Send(ms.GetBuffer(), (int)ms.Length);
```

Receiver:

```
IPEndPoint beaconEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), SharedData.udpPort);
byte[] receiveData = beaconClient.Receive(ref beaconEndpoint);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(receiveData);
CommData recieved = dataDeserializer.Deserialize(ms) as CommData;
```

Now I have to switch it over to use TCP. The sender seems to work fine, and is impressively simple:

```
dataSerializer.Serialize(senderClient.GetStream(), dataToSend, serNamespaceRemover);
```

But I'm having trouble with the receiver. I tried the simple, obvious thing:

```
NetworkStream netstr = client.GetStream();
CommData data = dataDeserializer.Deserialize(netstr) as CommData;
```

And I get the exception: There is an error in XML document (5, 14). The XML looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CommData>
  <RigName>Rig 100</RigName>
  <IsShutDown>false</IsShutDown>
</CommData>
```

So the 5,14 position is 2 chars after the end of the received data. I read the data into a char array, and confirmed that there is nothing after the end of the closing bracket, so I'm not sure what the deserializer is talking about.

Meanwhile, if I do this, then the receiver works:

```
NetworkStream netstr = client.GetStream();
byte[] arry = new byte[client.Available];
netstr.Read(arry, 0, client.Available);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arry);
CommData data = dataDeserializer.Deserialize(ms) as CommData;
```

This seems crazy. Why can't it just read directly from the NetworkStream? Do I really have to read the data into a MemoryStream and then pass it to the deserializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Deserializing data sent via TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739653/xmlserializer-deserialize-blocks-over-networkstream)

The answer there suggests that NetworkStream won't notify when the last byte is read. So it seems that your deserlializer keeps trying to read (even after reaching end; because NetworkStream doesn't notify it) from the NetworkStream and hence results in exception. You will need to read into MemoryStream.

Comment: Good catch, I was thinking along the same lines myself.  Saved me some research and I learned something new :)

Comment: [NetworkStream.DataAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx) is something close but don't think it will help in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know when you have received the entire XML file? As long as the remote end has not closed the connection, calling `Read` (which `XmlSerializer` will do) will block and wait for data.

Comment: I have actually had that problem before, but in this case, it isn't blocking but rather reading something invalid and throwing an exception.