# c# array of strings is not getting displayed

Tags: c#, sockets

The following is a simple server and client code segment written in c#. I want to send a string array from server and receive it from the client end and display on the console. But The string array is not getting displayed. Is there anything wrong in the code?

### **Server**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
            tcpListener.Start();  

            while (true)
            {                     
                TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];

                NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
                string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };

                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
                serializer.Serialize(tcpClient.GetStream(), arr1);

                int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);                 
                string id = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

                Console.WriteLine(id);              
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

### **Client**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                string stringData;

                TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
                NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();             

                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
                var stringArr = (string[])serializer.Deserialize(tcpClient.GetStream());

                foreach (string s in stringArr)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }

                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                ns.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input), 0, input.Length);
                ns.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `stringArr` not null? Any exceptions?

Comment: getting no exceptions but the string array is not getting displayed in the client console @Kamo

Comment: What is the trigger of `client` and `server` application to run?

Comment: please be more specific @Heinz Siahaan

Comment: @user5382101 I understand, that's why I asked you if `stringArr` is null after deserialization.

Comment: yes. stringArr is null after deserialization @Kamo

Comment: Duplicate of XmlSerializer.Deserialize blocks over NetworkStream

Answer (score 3):

I ran your code and it hanged at this line in the client

```
var stringArr = (string[])serializer.Deserialize(tcpClient.GetStream());
```

I then modified it so I read from the NetworkStream into a byte array first and then using a MemoryStream I deserialised the byte array. It then worked as I expected it to.

So it may be a problem using a NetworkStream with deserialisation.

[XmlSerializer.Deserialize blocks over NetworkStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739653/xmlserializer-deserialize-blocks-over-networkstream)

Looking at this Stackoverflow question, it appears that the XmlSerializer will carry on trying to read from the Stream until it reaches the end, which is causing your issue.

To fix, do as suggested and read the data you want to deserialise into a byte array first.

Comment: can you please provide me your modified code? @DanL